# How to download a base64-encoded image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64

I have a base64-encoded image from the server for which I want to force the download through JavaScript. Is is possible?

Answer (score 126):

1. If you want to download it using JavaScript (without any back-end) use:

   ```
   window.location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + img;
   ```

   where `img` is your base64 encoded image.
2. If you want to allow the user to specify a file name, use the `download` attribute of the `a` tag:

   ```
   <a download="FILENAME.EXT" href="data:image/png;base64,asdasd...">Download</a>
   ```

   - Notice: The download attribute is not supported by very old browsers

Comment: Thank you but the first option doesn't force the download

Comment: windows.location.href is not downloading image instead showing all the text

Comment: Just edit the a tag in the 2. solution and add `id="d"` and then call `document.getElementById("d").click();`

Comment: No one should use the second option, its a very heavy to use option. like, it lags a normal computer when downloading a 1080px encoded jpg file.

Comment: For me window.location.href worked but I need to add filename. How can I do that?

Answer (score 105):

Simple way to do this with Javascript...

```js
    var a = document.createElement("a"); //Create <a>
    a.href = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageBase64; //Image Base64 Goes here
    a.download = "Image.png"; //File name Here
    a.click(); //Downloaded file
```

Comment: If the file is too big like 4M chars it gives error

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My downloading is failing with "No internet" error. Although I am sure that the internet connection is good. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 45):

It is so simple just use function below:

```
// Parameters:
// contentType: The content type of your file. 
//              its like application/pdf or application/msword or image/jpeg or
//              image/png and so on
// base64Data: Its your actual base64 data
// fileName: Its the file name of the file which will be downloaded. 

function downloadBase64File(contentType, base64Data, fileName) {
     const linkSource = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`;
     const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
     downloadLink.href = linkSource;
     downloadLink.download = fileName;
     downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: thankx man! you are a life savor.
BTW, we dont need ```` `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`; ```` instead 
```` `${base64Data}`; ```` is enough

Comment: Poor performance when using base64 with length > 1000000

Answer (score 12):

I found this solution from the sourcecode of how Chrome takes full-page screenshots.

```js
const base64string = "";
const pageImage = new Image();
pageImage.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64string;
pageImage.onload = function() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = pageImage.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height= pageImage.naturalHeight;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.drawImage(pageImage, 0, 0);
    console.log(canvas, pageImage)
    saveScreenshot(canvas);
}
function saveScreenshot(canvas) {
    let fileName = "image"
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName + '.png';
    console.log(canvas)
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        console.log(blob)
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.click();
    });
};
```

Comment: I know you didn't write this.  And I'm willing to believe it works.  But.... seriously?  Creating a virtual link and then doing a virtual click?  Seems really hacky.

Comment: @TravisBear It's all right here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/emulation/DeviceModeView.js?q=saveScreenshot

Comment: @Sentient, Thanks it worked well with few customizations.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know whether am late to answer this, but I think the better solution could be this.

1. Create a file from the base64string

   ```js
   const convertBase64ToFile = (base64String, fileName) => {
        let arr = base64String.split(',');
        let mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
        let bstr = atob(arr[1]);
        let n = bstr.length;
        let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(n);
        while (n--) {
           uint8Array[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        let file = new File([uint8Array], fileName, { type: mime });
        return file;
   }
   ```
2. Install [File Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) from npm with

   ```
   npm install file-saver
   ```
3. Import [File Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

   ```js
   const { saveAs } = require('file-saver');
   /// OR 
   import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
   ```
4. Using [File Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) download the file

   ```js
   const downloadBase64Data = (base64String, fileName) => {
        let file = convertBase64ToFile(base64String, fileName);
        saveAs(file, fileName);
   }
   ```

*If this Answer has worked for you please upvote it and mark it as correct to help others easily find it*

Comment: fetch(base64File)
          .then(res => res.blob())
          .then(res => {
            saveAs(res, 'QR');
          })

Would save some lines.

Comment: saveAs return any Promise?

Comment: @Slowaways, I guess it returns a promise which resolves on success

Comment: @Garande return undefined

Comment: Is this more performant than @Ehsan's answer?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov It is quite performant, as you don't need to create/paint any html element, Try it out and send your feedback

Answer (score 8):

In my Angular  App, I am getting the base 64 files from server.

In Html:-

```
<button type="button" (click)="downloadFile(fileName,base64data,fileType)"></button>
```

In Ts:-

```
  downloadFile(fileName:string,data: any,fileFormat:string): void {
    const linkSource = 'data:'+fileFormat+';base64'+data;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Download Text File DataURL Demo</title>
        <style>
            body{ font: menu; }
        </style>
        <script src='//js.zapjs.com/js/download.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Download Text File DataURL Demo</h1>
        <main></main>
        <script>
            download("data:application/octet-stream;base64,YOUR BASE64URL", "dlDataUrlText.jpeg", "application/octet-stream;base64");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

download tag downloads the image using the script included.

For reference you can try this URL : http://danml.com/download.html

Comment: Attackers currently on js.zapjs.com might attempt to install dangerous programs on your computer that steal or delete your information.

Answer (score 3):

In my React App, I was getting the base 64 images from an API, I stored it in a global prop and downloaded it with the help of `<a>` tag.

```
<a href={`data:application/octet-stream;base64,${this.props.base64image}`} download={"imageName"}>Click to Download the image</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have it in base64, add the image tag in front of the base64. attach it to the element

```
png64 = "data:image/" + png64; 
$('#downloadPNG').attr('href', png64);
```

Add the file name that you want when downloading to the `download` tag.

```
<a download="chart.png" id="downloadPNG">Export img</a>
```

Comment: If the file is too big like 4M chars it gives error

Comment: you can try it. Try to download big images. https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-failed-network-error-when-downloading-on-google-chrome/

Comment: @canbax might it be due to too long URL? In such case you could try that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/5565538

Comment: @KasperSeweryn Thanks. I think I found that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

At first: This question is extremly browser dependent! I tried many, so I came up to answer this question that way:

You should put the base64-Data inside the src-Tag of an IMG-Element:
[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)
Then you can right click the Image and click "Save Image..." (or similar) in these browsers:

- Chrome 79
- Edge 44
- Firefox 71
- IE 11
- Safari 13

Also on Android with Chrome and Firefox.
Biggest file working was 23 MB PNG-File in IE 11 and Safari 13. But Firefox and Chrome did also work for 86 MB JPEG.