# convert base64 image file to jpg/png extension file

Tags: javascript, java, html, image

unable to download image having data base64 source

How can i convert base64 image to jpg/png file extension so that i can download image by passing image src to URL using java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a base64-encoded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011021/how-to-download-a-base64-encoded-image)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)