# Javascript: unable to download the base64 decoded image

Tags: javascript

I want to download an image in JS which is base64 encoded. For this, I have first decoded the image and tried to download it. The file is downloading but the content in the downloaded files are nothing.

The encoded image is like:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

I used the following code to decode and download the image:

`var imgdata = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';`

```
var imggetbase64decode = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""); // imgData is the encoded base64 string.

var data = imggetbase64decode, fileName = "my-download.png";
    var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        var json = data,
        blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I got the error during opening the downloaded file is:

> Could not load image 'my-download.png'.

Comment: In you code, it doesn't look like you are doing anything with `imggetbase64decode`. Is something else missing?

Comment: @msbit I've updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can get what you are looking for
[How to download a base64-encoded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011021/how-to-download-a-base64-encoded-image)

- if not please share some codepen link so i can help you out.