# How to download file from Laravel backend without storing in filesystem?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, download, base64, response

I have a `base64` encoded image which I want to send to my `vue frontend` for download. It seems that this is how it's done for images in your filesystem:

```
return response()->download($filePath);
```

but how would I do the same for a `base64` encoded image without having to store it in the filesystem? Something like:

```
return response()->download($base64Image);
```

shows that `the file doesn't exist`.

Answer (score 0):

You should send base64 content as string in http response not as attachment and take care to transform it from vuejs controller, example below:

```
// php
return response()->make($base64Image);
```

```
// js -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011021/how-to-download-a-base64-encoded-image
const img = api.getImage(); // base64 content
<a download="FILENAME.EXT" href="`data:image/png;base64,${img}`">Download</a>
```

`download()` method from `response()` helper expect `\SplFileInfo` or `string` of file path as first argument, so it can't work in your case.

```
    /**
     * Create a new file download response.
     *
     * @param  \SplFileInfo|string  $file
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @param  string|null  $disposition
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = [], $disposition = 'attachment');
```