# Converting API response to proper file type

Tags: javascript, api, response

I am working with an API that converts one file type to another file type. The response object looks a little strange to me. This particular response is a conversion from .pdf to .docx.
I do not understand why the **file** key in the response object looks as it is. What does it mean and how can I convert this to the required file type ?

````
fileName:"A file.docx"
file:"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"```
````

Comment: It's a Base64-encoded file. Take a look at how to download it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011021/how-to-download-a-base64-encoded-image

Answer (score 0):

That looks reasonable without testing, several issues whilst files are in transit they don't have the filename clear view embedded in their data so a filename is separate here it is `A file.docx`

Next issue is since you only know from the name or mime type which file format it is you cannot be certain its correct (why wrong file extensions may be used).

HOWEVER I think that looks like potential DocX or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document or perhaps another office format.

So how do I know? is because I see those files in transit like this one often, and most zips in transit start `UEsDB`

[image]

**how can I convert this to the required file type ?**

Well there are many methods using js atob function as probably simplest, unless you convert from base64 during save as docx via any available function.

Most OS scripts can do it in one line decode command, as above.

Comment: Pretty sure that OP looks for a way to convert Base64 to a file for downloading.